# How to Find and Expose the Ethernet Interfaces in a RHEL5 Iimage dd-ed to a Different Machine

Tags: linux, redhat, ethernet, powerpc

We captured the disk image off an IBM PS-703 (P-Series, i.e. Power-PC) BladeCenter using dd. in rescue mode.  The image is RedHat 5.11.  The goals were to have a backup image of the server and to be able to put that image onto two other servers, one production, one backup.

We built a new server using the image on an IBM PS-701 (P-Series) server.  This will be the new production machine.  The image was restored using dd in rescue mode.

The PS-701 boots and runs well with the installed backup image.  However, no Ethernet interfaces are present as reported by lspci.  lsdev is not available as our company image blocks it during install.

The original PS-703 reports the presence of two Broadcom NetXtreme Ethernet adapters.  As noted, the PS-701 sees no adapters.  The latest updates in IBM Fix Central suggest that the 701 has QLogic adapters but running lspci on another 701 shows that is has two IBM eHEA adapters. We are unsure which is correct.  The new machine shows you can not flash it through it's AMM.

Can anyone tell us how to determine the type(s) of Ethernet adapters in the 701?  Also, can you tell us which driver(s) to install?  And how to make the Ethernets visible?

**dmesg output**  added per request from Michael Hampton.

From a similar machine that is working:

```
Netfilter messages via NETLINK v0.30.
ip_conntrack version 2.4 (8192 buckets, 65536 max) - 304 bytes per  conntrack
IBM eHEA ethernet device driver (Release EHEA_0092-05)
ehea: eth0: Jumbo frames are enabled
ehea: eth0 -> logical port id #1
ehea: eth1: Jumbo frames are enabled
ehea: eth1 -> logical port id #2
ehea: eth0: Physical port up
ehea: External switch port is backup port
8021q: adding VLAN 0 to HW filter on device eth0
```

and from the non-working machine:

```
Using pSeries machine description
Page orders: linear mapping = 24, virtual = 16, io = 12
Found initrd at 0xc000000002b80000:0xc000000002f40800
Partition configured for 16 cpus.
Starting Linux PPC64 #1 SMP Fri May 1 10:40:05 EDT 2015
-----------------------------------------------------
ppc64_pft_size                = 0x1d
physicalMemorySize            = 0x7a0000000
ppc64_caches.dcache_line_size = 0x80
ppc64_caches.icache_line_size = 0x80
htab_address                  = 0x(null)
htab_hash_mask                = 0x3fffff
-----------------------------------------------------
Linux version 2.6.18-406.el5 (mockbuild@ppc-032.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) (gcc v
ersion 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-55)) #1 SMP Fri May 1 10:40:05 EDT 2015
[boot]0012 Setup Arch
Node 0 Memory: 0x0-0x7a0000000
EEH: PCI Enhanced I/O Error Handling Enabled
PPC64 nvram contains 15360 bytes
Using dedicated idle loop
On node 0 totalpages: 499712
  DMA zone: 499712 pages, LIFO batch:1
[boot]0015 Setup Done
Built 1 zonelists.  Total pages: 499712
Kernel command line: root=/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 ro console=hvc0 rhgb quiet
[boot]0020 XICS Init
xics: no ISA interrupt controller
[boot]0021 XICS Done
PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 12, 32768 bytes)
time_init: decrementer frequency = 512.000000 MHz
time_init: processor frequency   = 3000.000000 MHz
Console: colour dummy device 80x25
Dentry cache hash table entries: 4194304 (order: 9, 33554432 bytes)
Inode-cache hash table entries: 2097152 (order: 8, 16777216 bytes)
freeing bootmem node 0
Memory: 31873344k/31981568k available (5056k kernel code, 108224k reserved, 1344
k data, 1257k bss, 320k init)
Calibrating delay loop... 1021.95 BogoMIPS (lpj=510976)
Security Framework v1.0.0 initialized
SELinux:  Initializing.
SELinux:  Starting in permissive mode
selinux_register_security:  Registering secondary module capability
Capability LSM initialized as secondary
Mount-cache hash table entries: 4096
Processor 1 found.
Processor 2 found.
Processor 3 found.
Processor 4 found.
Processor 5 found.
Processor 6 found.
Processor 7 found.
Processor 8 found.
Processor 9 found.
Processor 10 found.
Processor 11 found.
Processor 12 found.
Processor 13 found.
Processor 14 found.
Processor 15 found.
Brought up 16 CPUs
Node 0 CPUs: 0-15
sizeof(vma)=176 bytes
sizeof(page)=56 bytes
sizeof(inode)=560 bytes
sizeof(dentry)=216 bytes
sizeof(ext3inode)=760 bytes
sizeof(buffer_head)=96 bytes
sizeof(skbuff)=248 bytes
migration_cost=0,691
checking if image is initramfs... it is
Freeing initrd memory: 3842k freed
NET: Registered protocol family 16
PCI: Probing PCI hardware
IOMMU table initialized, virtual merging enabled
mapping IO 3dffc01f0000 -> d0000800000f0000, size: 10000
mapping IO 3dffc02f0000 -> d0000800001f0000, size: 10000
PCI: Probing PCI hardware done
Registering pmac pic with sysfs...
No pciex nodes found
No pcix nodes found
usbcore: registered new driver usbfs
usbcore: registered new driver hub
NetLabel: Initializing
NetLabel:  domain hash size = 128
NetLabel:  protocols = UNLABELED CIPSOv4
NetLabel:  unlabeled traffic allowed by default
NET: Registered protocol family 2
IP route cache hash table entries: 1048576 (order: 7, 8388608 bytes)
TCP established hash table entries: 1048576 (order: 8, 16777216 bytes)
TCP bind hash table entries: 65536 (order: 4, 1048576 bytes)
TCP: Hash tables configured (established 1048576 bind 65536)
TCP reno registered
vio_bus_init: processing c00000079fffcd98
vio_bus_init: processing c00000079fffcf50
vio_bus_init: processing c00000079fffd088
vio_bus_init: processing c00000079fffd1e0
vio_bus_init: processing c00000079fffd338
IBM eBus Device Driver
scan-log-dump not implemented on this system
RTAS daemon started
RTAS: event: 19, Type: Platform Error, Severity: 2
audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
type=2000 audit(1440014763.530:1): initialized
Total HugeTLB memory allocated, 0
VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.5.1
Dquot-cache hash table entries: 8192 (order 0, 65536 bytes)
SELinux:  Registering netfilter hooks
Initializing Cryptographic API
alg: No test for crc32c (crc32c-generic)
ksign: Installing public key data
Loading keyring
- Added public key D8CAB7B6B14A884
- User ID: Red Hat, Inc. (Kernel Module GPG key)
io scheduler noop registered
io scheduler anticipatory registered
io scheduler deadline registered
io scheduler cfq registered (default)
pci_hotplug: PCI Hot Plug PCI Core version: 0.5
rpaphp: RPA HOT Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.1
vio_register_driver: driver hvc_console registering
HVSI: registered 0 devices
Generic RTC Driver v1.07
Linux agpgart interface v0.101 (c) Dave Jones
Serial: 8250/16550 driver $Revision: 1.90 $ 4 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
brd: module loaded
Uniform Multi-Platform E-IDE driver Revision: 7.00alpha2
ide: Assuming 33MHz system bus speed for PIO modes; override with idebus=xx
ide-floppy driver 0.99.newide
usbcore: registered new driver hiddev
usbcore: registered new driver usbhid
drivers/usb/input/hid-core.c: v2.6:USB HID core driver
mice: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
md: md driver 0.90.3 MAX_MD_DEVS=256, MD_SB_DISKS=27
md: bitmap version 4.39
TCP bic registered
Initializing IPsec netlink socket
NET: Registered protocol family 1
NET: Registered protocol family 17
Initalizing network drop monitor service
Freeing unused kernel memory: 320k freed
PCI: Enabling device: (0001:00:01.2), cmd 142
ehci_hcd 0001:00:01.2: EHCI Host Controller
ehci_hcd 0001:00:01.2: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
ehci_hcd 0001:00:01.2: irq 307, io mem 0x3b00ffffd000
ehci_hcd 0001:00:01.2: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00, driver 10 Dec 2004
usb usb1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
hub 1-0:1.0: 5 ports detected
ohci_hcd: 2005 April 22 USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver (PCI)
ohci_hcd 0001:00:01.0: OHCI Host Controller
ohci_hcd 0001:00:01.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
ohci_hcd 0001:00:01.0: irq 305, io mem 0x3b00ffffe000
usb usb2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
hub 2-0:1.0: 3 ports detected
ohci_hcd 0001:00:01.1: OHCI Host Controller
ohci_hcd 0001:00:01.1: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
ohci_hcd 0001:00:01.1: irq 306, io mem 0x3b00fffff000
usb usb3: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
hub 3-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver v3.0
SCSI subsystem initialized
libata version 3.00 loaded.
ipr: IBM Power RAID SCSI Device Driver version: 2.5.3 (March 10, 2012)
ipr 0000:00:01.0: Found IOA with IRQ: 289
ipr 0000:00:01.0: Starting IOA initialization sequence.
ipr 0000:00:01.0: Adapter firmware version: 04200015
ipr 0000:00:01.0: IOA initialized.
scsi0 : IBM 57D0 Storage Adapter
  Vendor: IBM-ESXS  Model: ST9600204SS       Rev: B541
  Type:   Direct-Access                      ANSI SCSI revision: 05
SCSI device sda: 1172123568 512-byte hdwr sectors (600127 MB)
sda: Write Protect is off
sda: Mode Sense: df 00 10 08
SCSI device sda: drive cache: write through w/ FUA
SCSI device sda: 1172123568 512-byte hdwr sectors (600127 MB)
sda: Write Protect is off
sda: Mode Sense: df 00 10 08
SCSI device sda: drive cache: write through w/ FUA
 sda: sda1 sda2 sda3
sd 0:2:0:0: Attached scsi disk sda
  Vendor: IBM       Model: VSBPD1BK   SAS    Rev:   01
  Type:   Enclosure                          ANSI SCSI revision: 02
scsi: unknown device type 31
  Vendor: IBM       Model: 57D0001SISIOA     Rev: 0150
  Type:   Unknown                            ANSI SCSI revision: 00
device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
device-mapper: ioctl: 4.11.6-ioctl (2011-02-18) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
device-mapper: dm-raid45: initialized v0.2594l
kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds
EXT3-fs: mounted filesystem with ordered data mode.
SELinux:  Disabled at runtime.
SELinux:  Unregistering netfilter hooks
type=1404 audit(1440014784.958:2): selinux=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295
sd 0:2:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
scsi 0:8:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 13
scsi 0:255:255:255: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 31
lp: driver loaded but no devices found
md: Autodetecting RAID arrays.
md: autorun ...
md: ... autorun DONE.
device-mapper: multipath: version 1.0.6 loaded
loop: loaded (max 8 devices)
EXT3 FS on dm-0, internal journal
kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds
EXT3 FS on sda2, internal journal
EXT3-fs: mounted filesystem with ordered data mode.
Adding 50102144k swap on /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol01.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across
:50102144k
Loading iSCSI transport class v2.0-871.
802.1Q VLAN Support v1.8 Ben Greear <greearb@candelatech.com>
All bugs added by David S. Miller <davem@redhat.com>
libcxgbi:libcxgbi_init_module: tag itt 0x1fff, 13 bits, age 0xf, 4 bits.
libcxgbi:ddp_setup_host_page_size: system PAGE 65536, ddp idx 3.
Chelsio T3 iSCSI Driver cxgb3i v2.0.0 (Jun. 2010)
iscsi: registered transport (cxgb3i)
IPv6: Loaded, but administratively disabled, reboot required to enable
cnic: Broadcom NetXtreme II CNIC Driver cnic v2.5.12 (June 29, 2012)
Broadcom NetXtreme II iSCSI Driver bnx2i v2.7.2.2 (Jun 18, 2012)
iscsi: registered transport (bnx2i)
iscsi: registered transport (tcp)
iscsi: registered transport (iser)
iscsi: registered transport (be2iscsi)
ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
Netfilter messages via NETLINK v0.30.
ip_conntrack version 2.4 (8192 buckets, 65536 max) - 304 bytes per conntrack
Bluetooth: Core ver 2.10
NET: Registered protocol family 31
Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
Bluetooth: L2CAP ver 2.8
Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.8
Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.1
usb 1-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 2
usb 1-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
hub 1-1:1.0: 2 ports detected
usb 1-1.2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3
usb 1-1.2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
hub 1-1.2:1.0: USB hub found
hub 1-1.2:1.0: 4 ports detected
usb 1-1.2.3: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
usb 1-1.2.3: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
scsi1 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
usb-storage: device found at 4
usb-storage: waiting for device to settle before scanning
usbcore: registered new driver usb-storage
USB Mass Storage support registered.
  Vendor: MATSHITA  Model: UJDA780 DVD/CDRW  Rev: CA22
  Type:   CD-ROM                             ANSI SCSI revision: 00
scsi 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 5
usb-storage: device scan complete
usb 1-1.2.3: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 24x/24x writer cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
usb 1-1: USB disconnect, address 2
usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, address 3
usb 1-1.2.3: USB disconnect, address 4
usb 1-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 5
usb 1-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
hub 1-1:1.0: 2 ports detected
usb 1-1.2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 6
usb 1-1.2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
hub 1-1.2:1.0: USB hub found
hub 1-1.2:1.0: 4 ports detected
usb 1-1.2.3: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 7
usb 1-1.2.3: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
scsi2 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
usb-storage: device found at 7
usb-storage: waiting for device to settle before scanning
  Vendor: MATSHITA  Model: UJDA780 DVD/CDRW  Rev: CA22
  Type:   CD-ROM                             ANSI SCSI revision: 00
sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 24x/24x writer cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
sr 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
sr 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 5
usb-storage: device scan complete
ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 3
ISO 9660 Extensions: RRIP_1991A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you post dmesg output?

Generally speaking, the best way to figure this out is to look in the chassis management module. It should have an option to enumerate devices within the blade.

(I would comment, but low rep)

EDIT: I no longer have a valid IBM support entitlement, so I can't link you directly, but it looks like you have the eHEA model. There should be drivers hanging off the PS701 support pages. In addition, there's an open source driver you can try here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ibmehcad/

I would still encourage you to check the CMM for the full hardware inventory of the blade, because I'm just guessing on the basis of your other output. Another option is to try lsvpd, which you only get if you install the IBM support/service tools (or run AIX).

Comment: +1 You're doing all the right things to rightfully earn reputation.  Keep up the good work :-)

Comment: As far as I know, everything that might be needed is on IBM Fix Central.

Comment: Well my co-worker who is actually dealing with this issue finally gave up and started over from scratch.  Thanks for the help.